# Users not writing to database (Postgresql)

Tags: django, django-models

When I create a user with my custom user model I cannot sign in. It just keeps telling me `Please enter a correct email and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.` I thought I should check if I can see my test user in the db. I know only staff accounts can login to the admin but I'm using a different login form.

If I'm not mistaken it looks like there aren't any users in my database.

```
myproject=# \dt accounts_user
                 List of relations
 Schema |     Name      | Type  |      Owner       
--------+---------------+-------+------------------
 public | accounts_user | table | myprojectuser
(1 row)
```

Here's my user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, 
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin,
)

# Create your models here.


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, company, phone, is_active=True, is_admin=False, is_staff=False, is_dealer=False, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a first name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a last name")
        if not company:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a company")
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a phone number")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.first_name = first_name
        user_obj.last_name = last_name
        user_obj.company = company
        user_obj.phone = phone
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.dealer = is_dealer
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, company, phone, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            company,
            phone,
            password=password,
            is_admin=True,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user
```

Perhaps there's something wrong in my admin.py?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Register your models here.

User = get_user_model()

admin.site.register(User)
```

Hopefully someone can help me as I'm really stuck here.

Comment: why are you using properties instead of naming the fields `is_<attribute_name>` in model?

Comment: also try to create a superuser via console: `py manage.py createsuperuser` and see if this works first of all

Comment: @ruddra I just followed a tutorial on youtube. Could you show me in an answer how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for your reply. I have created a superuser and am able to sign in just fine through both login forms

Comment: @GTA.sprx how do you create your test users? console or admin?

Comment: @Jonas The admin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why your issue arises (considered you enterer it in the correct format), but this should give you a basic working solution to build upon:

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Adjusting the default UserCreationForm
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', # etc.]
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import User

admin.site.register(User)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser

# Inherit from AbstractBaseUser to extend User Model

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login
    online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dealer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Also I am not sure which tutorial ([this?](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser)) you followed, but personally I don't have models both in `models.py` and `admin.py`.

**Login extension - views.py**

```
# function for login logic
def loginPage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # get input values
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        # check if user has account in db
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('render_calculator')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)

def registerPage(request):
    # define the form, in this case Djangos default UserCreation
    form = CreateUserForm()

    # check if form inputs are valid after submitting, the save 'post' user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Save User to db
            form.save()

            # get input values
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            email = request.POST.get('email')

            return redirect('render_login')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

**login.html**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="formFieldLoginContainer">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="loginSubmitButton" name="Login User" value="Login">
    <div id="noAccountDiv"> Don't have an account yet?
        <a href="/register" id="noAccountLink">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

**register.html**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <!-- loop form object and create div for each form field included -->
    {% for field in form %}

    <div class="formFieldContainer">
            <div class="registerLabel">{{field.label}}</div>
            <div class="registerField">{{field}}</div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}

    <!-- render possible input form errors -->
    {{form.errors}}
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="Create User" value="Register">
    <div id="alreadyAccountDiv"> Already have an account?
        <a href="/login" id="alreadyAccountLink">Login</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

**ulrs.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name='render_login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view),
    path('email/', include(mail_urls)),
    path('password/', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
]
```

Comment: Whoops I meant to paste my admin.py. I updated my question. I just need my user model to do two things: 1: allow users to login with email and 2: differentiate between company staff and dealer accounts so I can choose what urls dealer accounts can see

Comment: @GTA.sprx see my extended answer. Using these templates user can sign-up and login and if you want to separate the user permissions just use `is.staff` boolean like you already did. Thats it ;)